# Calling a linkbutton click with jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I've got a textbox, I want a function to be called onkeyup, for that reason I've got a hidden button that is trying to redirect to another c# function. The problem is jquery goes inside the function, but then doesn't go to the server side event.

Here's my HTML for both elements:

```
                    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Име:</span>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbCliName" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" onkeyup="runQuery(this)" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="hiddenButton" class="btn btn-default" Style="opacity: 0;" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="hiddenButton_Click" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Егн/Булстат:</span>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbEgnBStat" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Here's my jquery funtion:

```
function runQuery(e) {
    $('#hiddenButton').click();
}
```

And the C# for the button click:

```
protected void hiddenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AutoComplete_Press(tbCliName.Text);
}
```

EDIT with Ajax:

function runQuery(e) {
var search = $(e).val();

```
function runQuery(e) {
    var search = $(e).val();
    var params = {

        url: 'addEditProduct.ascx/AutoComplete_Press',
        method: 'post',
        contentType: 'aapplication/json',
        data: '{searchClause:' + search + '}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(1);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(2);
        }
    };

    $.ajax(params);
}



   [WebMethod]
    public static void AutoComplete_Press(string searchClause)
    {
        int searchType = 0; //ЕГН
        int csKind = 0;

        Regex regex = new Regex("^[0-9]+$");
        if (!regex.IsMatch(searchClause))
            searchType = 1;

        //if (rbLP.Checked)
        //    csKind = 1;

        string clients = laboratory.getClients2(searchType, searchClause, 1);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "jQuery goes inside the function"?  Where/how specifically is this failing?  What's the HTML for the element being clicked?

Comment: The element being clicked is the hiddenButton. It goes inside the jquery function as in if I put a "debugger;" it stops there.

Comment: Ok, but what is the actual HTML for the element(s) in question?  By "inside the jQuery function" do you mean that your `runQuery` function is being executed?  Does the jQuery selector find anything when you debug it?

Comment: I updated my question with more HTML. The selector finds the button with no problem.

Comment: That's still the server-side code.  JavaScript doesn't interact with server-side code, it only sees the actual resulting client-side HTML.  You need to look at the resulting HTML that's in your browser as part of your debugging efforts.  (Basically, when something isn't working, never *assume* that the generated code is what you expect it to be.  Inspect it and verify.)  And specifically how have you confirmed that the jQuery selector finds the target element?  I know it's a lot of detail work, but it's standard debugging when a problem is encountered.

Comment: I just did
debugger; 
var a = $('#hiddenButton'):
Put in a value in the textbox and then hovered the variable and it had the properties for the button.

Answer (score 1):

try using webmethod. In server side

```
[WebMethod]
public static void BindData()
{
  AutoComplete_Press(tbCliName.Text);
}
```

And in client side

```
 $("#hiddenButton").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.aspx/BindData",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({/*pass values here*/}),
            dataType: "json",      
        });
    });
```

Refer below link 
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-server-side-methods-using-JavaScript-and-JQuery-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: This doesn't work since I can't refference non-static fields.

Comment: Updated question with the ajax code it doesn't go inside the c# again.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it is not working is that you are using `asp:LinkButton` which is rendered as `a` element with `href` attribute set to `javascript:__doPostBack()`.

If you replace `asp:LinkButton` to `asp:Button` calling `$('#hiddenButton').click();` will start to work.

Just change this line of code

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="hiddenButton" class="btn btn-default" Style="opacity: 0;" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="hiddenButton_Click" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
```

to this

```
<asp:Button ID="hiddenButton" class="btn btn-default" Style="opacity: 0;" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="hiddenButton_Click" runat="server"></asp:Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke function like this but not event 
Create a Web Method and try Jquery Ajax

```
var params = {
                url: 'Index.aspx/YourWebmethod',
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true,
                data: JSON.stringify(data to be send ), 
                success: function (result) {
                    alert('Success');
                },
                error: function (result) { alert('Warning! It failed.'); }
            };
            $.ajax(params);
```